# Laurent series of $z\mapsto\frac{z^4}{z^2-1}$ in $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to calculate the Laurent series and the main part in $\infty$ of $$f:z\mapsto\frac{z^4}{z^2-1}.$$

The Taylor series of $f(\frac{1}{z})$ in $0$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2(n-1)}=1/z^2+1+z^2+z^4+...$$

What is the Laurent series in $\infty$ and what the main part in $\infty$? How do I get them?

Comment: You have already obtained them, they are in your own answer.

Comment: So the Laurent series of $f$ in $\infty$ is the Laurent series of $f(1/z)$ in $0$? And what is the main part?

Comment: WolframAlpha says that the expension in $\infty$ is $z^2 + 1 +1/z^2+1/z^4+1/z^6+...$ This is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, do $\;z\to\frac1z\;$ and develop around zero:

$$f\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac{\frac1{z^4}}{\frac1{z^2}-1}=\frac1{z^2-z^4}=\frac1{z^2}\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac1{z^2}\left(1+z^2+z^4+\ldots\right)=...$$

Comment: Yes, this is what I got. And this is the Laurent series in $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way to go.

Comment: Okay, and what is now the main part?

Comment: If you mean *the principal part* that is the part with the negative powers of the $\;z\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, i mean this. I am a little confused because WolframAlpha says that the Laurent series in $\infty$ is $z^2+1+1/z^2+1/z^4+1/z^6+...$.

Comment: Well, yes: by going back to $\;z\;$ from $\;\frac1z\;$ , we get the expansion at $\;z=\infty\;$ : $$z^2+1+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^4}+\ldots...$$

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to computing the series of $f$ around $\infty$ is to first write the series of $f(\frac 1 z)$ around $0$, and then substitute $\frac 1 z$ instead of $z$ in the result. In your case,

$$f(\frac 1 z) = \frac {\frac 1 {z^4}} {\frac 1 {z^2} - 1} = \frac {1} {z^2 - z^4} = \frac 1 {z^2} (1 + z^2 + z^4 + \dots) = \frac 1 {z^2} + 1 + z^2 + z^4 + \dots$$

and replacing now $z$ by $\frac 1 z$ you get

$$f(z) = z^2 + 1 + \frac 1 {z^2} + \frac 1 {z^4} + \dots .$$

By definition, the [principal part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Principal_part) of a Laurent series is the sum of the terms with *negative* powers, which in your case means $\frac 1 {z^2} + \frac 1 {z^4} + \dots$.